# delete rows from both DataGridView and database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm searching all over every forum but I can't find the solution. It should be easy but it doesn't work.

I have created `DataGridView` called "doctorsDataGridView" that has Doctors Table as source.
I don't want to allow the user to add items but allow removing and editing. For the deleting first I put this code:

```
private void doctorsDataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the balance column whenever rows are deleted.
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Doctors] WHERE ([DoctorCode] = @code)", Welcome.con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = doctorsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DoctorCode"].Value;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
}

private void doctorsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.doctorsBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.clincDataSet);
}

private void AllDoctors_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'clincDataSet.Doctors' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.doctorsTableAdapter.Fill(this.clincDataSet.Doctors);
}
```

But when I try to delete any row it's only deleted from the `DatagridView` and not the database.

Comment: Dumb question, but have you substituted the value returned from `doctorsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DoctorCode"].Value` into your SQL query in Management Studio and verified the query works directly on the database?

Comment: And just to clarify I meant my question was dumb not yours (incase it came across that way).

Comment: @DanielKelley i don't really get your question , i sorry

Comment: You are executing SQL. have you checked it works directly on the database with the blue from your cell?

Comment: Just to clarify, even though it is pretty clear but this seems strange, it is definitely removed from the `DataGridView` and not the database?

Comment: I'm only asking because I've had the reverse of the problem happen where rows were removed from SQL and not my `DataGridView` due to improper binding.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help but try changing `cmd.Parameters.Add` to use the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method instead. I know that's solved some issues for me in the past.

Comment: @DanielKelley yes i have checked and its working

Comment: @LeonNewswanger it deletes from the DataGridView but not the database

Comment: @LeonNewswanger i will try this and tell you if working

Comment: Yet another dumb question, but have you inserted a breakpoint or done something similar to make sure that your RowsRemoved handler is actually being called?

Answer (score 3):

Try to place your code in [`DataGridView.UserDeletingRow Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow.aspx)

```
private void doctorsDataGridView_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the balance column whenever rows are deleted.
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Doctors] WHERE ([DoctorCode] = @code)", Welcome.con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = doctorsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DoctorCode"].Value;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong here but I'd do following if I were you:

- Open SQL Server profiler and see if anything gets to SQL server in the first place
- Check your database references? Is Doctors table referenced by some other table? Maybe that is preventing you from deleting data
- Step through code using debugger and check out SQL statement before executing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() - try executing same statement manually in SSMS

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your sql command Execute correctly ?
MSDN: "ExecuteNoneQuery() For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command" , so your ExecuteNonewQuery() must return 1;

Note: The datagridview rowsremoved event gets called every time the data gets loaded. It also makes sense to a certain extent that every time the data loads, the existing rows are removed. so technically the event should get called.

You could have a private boolean variable to know when you are loading and when you are not.

```
    private bool IsLoading { get; set; }

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsLoading = true;
// do stuff
    this.IsLoading = false;
}

private void DataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
            if (!this.IsLoading)
            {
                return;
            }

   //do stuff
}
```